# a good way to check if timer already run repeatedly

Tags: android, react-native, service, timer

I'm working on React Native and i want to create a never ending service that run every (n) seconds on Native Modules (on this topic is android).

I've create a simple service like this

```
public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        Log.v(TAG, "SERVICE RUN");
        try{
          if(haveNetworkConnection()){
            db.openDB();
            if(db.countRowNewStructure()>0){
              //send data to server
            } else{
              Log.v(TAG, "No data should be send to server");
            }
          } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Ga ada sinyal");
          }
        } catch (JSONException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }, 0, 1000);
  }
```

above code run every second to check, but i'm facing the problem when i re-run the service from React Native, the log showing me those code every 0.5 seconds

the simulation may be like :

```
0----------------1 //seconds
startTimer()
        re-run startTimer() conscious
        0----------------1 //seconds
        startTimer()

//now i have two startTimer() that will run every 1 sec on different interval
```

I want to keep my startTimer() just running once even I trigger `startService()` every 0.5 sec.

how can i do that? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> this may help you.  Timmer to perform the certain action in android after the particular time.

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
         Timer timer = new Timer();
         TimerTask timertaskforsynctime = new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
               // your action here    

                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timertaskforsynctime,5000,10000);// decide the time when it will start and after how much time it will run continusly.

}`
```

> for one time

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // your code that will run after 1 sec
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: the Timer still running more than one https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Dqd.png as you see my SERVICE RUN show less than a second

Comment: will you please elaborate? service will end automatically if you dont make it foreground within 4 or 5 seconds, this condition is from android 8.0.

Comment: i tried it on API 22, and my question is about avoid `Timer` running twice btw, it's different condition like you say

Comment: well bro you need timer one way or  the other, but this timer will run untill you stop it without running the serverice, you dont need to start to service to perform task continuestly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `cancel` method to cancel the previous `Timer`.

```java
public class YourModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
   Timer tim = new Timer();

   public void startTimer() {
    tim.cancel();
    tim = new Timer();
    tim.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {
            // Run tasks
          }
        },
        0,
        1000);
  }


}
```